# Photoshop - Gradient Overlay

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, gradient

I'm having such a fool problem...
I'm trying to achieve this effect below by using Phtoshop Gradient tool, left color set to #2b2e35 (100% opacity) and right #fff (0% opacity) and dragging a line from the left border to the right border. But I'm not achieving the same effect as the image below. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Gradient Effect]

Comment: You're referring to the dark-to-light gradient that is in the whole image, right?

Comment: Yup, and the left side being darker and blueish (#2b2e35)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the gradient layer on top of the image, and change the blend mode setting (on the gradient layer) to multiply.

Comment: Oh god, how could I forget about Layer Settings, lol. And a + for this answer, I had to add 2 gradients in the same layer, one for all background, and another to apply only in the left border (darker).

Answer (score 0):

When using the Gradient tool, choose the second type as highlighted below. What this does is create a solid to transparent gradient, meaning, you set your desired start color (#2b2e35) and then it fades that out without the need to set white at the other end.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, this one I was aware of.